# Is servlet also a kind of RPC?

Tags: servlets, rpc

As far as I understand, RPC is a client-server model while the client sends some requests to the server side and get some results back. Then, is Java servlet also a kind of RPC which uses HTTP protocol? Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the very first sentence of the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) on RPC:

> In computer science, a remote procedure call (RPC) is an inter-process communication that allows a computer program to cause a subroutine or procedure to execute in another address space (commonly on another computer on a shared network) without the programmer explicitly coding the details for this remote interaction.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) That is, the programmer writes essentially the same code whether the subroutine is local to the executing program, or remote.

So, Servlets would be an RPC mechanism if you could invoke a servlet from a client using

```
SomeResult r = someObject.doSomething();
```

That's not the case at all. To invoke a servlet, you need to explicitely send a HTTP request and encode parameters in the way the servlet expects them, then read and parse the response.